# Fortify scan integrate in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, fortify

I do not see the fortify plugin listed in the pipeline syntax.

```
mvn sca:clean sca:translate sca:scan
```

The above command does not execute.
I get the following:

No plugin found for prefix 'sca' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using that command, you must install the Fortify Maven plugin. It's located in [Fortify install]/Samples/Advanced/Maven Plugin. There's a readme there with the details, it's just one command but check your readme for the syntax.

Comment: The fortify scan works fine and I have the .fpr files generated in the respective target folders.
Is there a way to have a visual report in Jenkins for the fortify results?